# Application not running in Java SE 7

Tags: java, command-line

I made a litte game in java (NetBeans), but it doesn't seem to work in Java 7, although I compiled it with **JDK 5**.

The following command prompt using the **current version of java** works:

```
java -jar "C:\Users\ ... \Vier_gewinnt.jar"
```

The following command prompt doesn't work. Nothing happens, no error message or Java exception is printed. It uses **Java SE 7u80** (Windows x86), downloaded from [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html).

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "C:\Users\ ... \Vier_gewinnt.jar"
```

I don't know very much about command prompts, mabye I made a mistake. Can anyone help me to make it work?

Comment: `java.exe` and `javaw.exe` is not the same. Try dropping the `w`.

Comment: And hint: why on earth are you compiling with JDK **5**? Java 5 has had end-of-life many years in the past. When you are new to java, and starting to learn it: use Java8; and don't worry about JDKs that were outdated long before you even thought about learning java.

Comment: I tested the application on 4 computers: My PC, my mothers PC, my sisters PC and my sisters laptop, but on 3 of them was Java 7 or older installed. So I thought that it might be helpful to make my application backward compatible.

Comment: @Andreas `java.exe` worked! The java exception was displayed, so I could fix it. Now it works properly.